# Fragmented Image byte array over socket

Tags: android, image, sockets, arrays

Im trying to send an image as a byte array over a socket to a client so it can view the image, and all goes well except when viewing the image its fragmented, i can view the top 10th of the image but the rest of it is grey and black pixels and i cant figure out why

heres a piece of my server code:

```
    public synchronized void nextFrame(VideoFrame frame) {
        // This method is called when a new frame is ready.
        // Don't forget to recycle it when done dealing with the frame.

        // draw the new frame onto the JLabel
            go = true;
            pic = frame.getBytes();
            go = false;
            label.getGraphics().drawImage(frame.getBufferedImage(), 0, 0, width, height, null);
            frame.recycle();

    }
}

class server extends Thread{
    int port;
    ServerSocket socket;
    Socket temps = null;
    boolean go = true;
    server(int p){
        port = p;
        start();
    }

    public void run(){      

        while(go == true){
            try {
                socket = new ServerSocket(port, 10);
                socket.setSoTimeout(10000);
                temps = socket.accept();
                new connect(temps);
                port += 1;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                if(e.getMessage().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Accept timed out")){
                    go = false;
                }else{
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            }

        }
        try {
            socket.close();
            System.out.println("Closing socket server(no more connections will be created)");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class connect extends Thread{
    Socket connection;
    ObjectOutputStream out;
    int port;
    String host;
    GetInput in;
    connect(Socket s){
        try {
            connection = s;
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            host = connection.getInetAddress().getHostName();
            port = connection.getPort();
            System.out.println("Connected to " + host + ":" + port);
            in = new GetInput(connection);
            start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }

    public void run(){
        try {
            out.writeInt(Main.pic.length);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        while(in.isAlive()){
            if(Main.go){    
                try {
                    out.write(Main.pic);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.getMessage().toString();
                }
            }
        }
        try {
            out.close();
            connection.close();
            System.out.println("Closing " + host + ":" + port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
class GetInput extends Thread{
    ObjectInputStream in;
    GetInput(Socket s){
        try {
            in = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        start();
    }
    public void run(){
        try{
            boolean go = in.readBoolean();
            int a = (go?1:0);
            System.out.println(a);
        } catch (IOException e) {
                e.getMessage().toString();
        }
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

i know the frame grabber is grabbing the image right because im also displaying the image on the server and it looks fine, so that means the byte arrays not getting sent over the sockets correctly, but why?

EDIT: heres my client code, its an android app

```
package org.smiley.doom;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ClientActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

    Socket s;
    InetAddress inet;
    ObjectOutputStream out;
    ObjectInputStream in;
    TextView log;
    ImageView im;
    Button send;
    EditText tip;
    int rport;
    String ip;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        tip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etIP);
        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSEND);
        im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivPIC);
        log = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLog);

        s = null;
        in = null;
        out = null;

        send.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        switch(arg0.getId()){
            case R.id.bSEND:
                final int len;
                    try {
                        inet = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.2");
                        s = new Socket(inet, 4321);
                        in = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                        out = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                        log.setText("Client opened");
                        len = in.readInt();
                        new Thread(new Runnable(){

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                    byte[] b = new byte[len];
                                    try {
                                        in.read(b);
                                        log.setText(""+s.getReceiveBufferSize());
                                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                                        e1.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    final byte[] l = b;
                                    im.post(new Runnable(){
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(l, 0, l.length);
                                            im.setImageBitmap(bmp);                             
                                        }
                                    });
                                    try {
                                        out.writeBoolean(true);
                                        out.close();
                                        in.close();
                                        s.close();
                                        //log.setText("Client closed");
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                            }

                        }).start();;
                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to post the client code. This is incomplete and unanswerable as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCP only delivers as many bytes to the application as currently available. Since the underlying network layer (IP) is packet based, your stream is getting chunked into parts during transmission. Network stack on the receiving side gets these chunks (packets) off the network card and buffers them until an application reads from given socket, at which point you get `min` of your buffer size and what's piled up in the OS per-socket buffer.

Because TCP connection represents a *stream*, the OS doesn't know anything about your application messages, so it's your responsibility to reassemble everything back together.

You have to read from the socket in a loop until you know you have all your data. The easiest way to know that is to tell the client upfront how many bytes you are going to send.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are your data segment (image) is much larger than your buffer.

Somehow, you have to find a way to buffer the output so you can flush it before you overflow your write buffer.

Comment: it seems your right im receiving 1020 bytes when i need to be receiving 37 times that, the weird thing is i checked both my receiving buffer size and my sending buffer size and both of them are bigger than the size of the picture its self

Answer (score 0):

Nikolai Fetissov's answer helped me solve the issue. Here's how I got it to work:

1. Send a JSON (or any other format) containing the expected message
   size and message type from sender to receiver. Make sure this is
   short and sweet.
2. Immediately send your data. It could be an image/audio/video or anything.

Bonus: This will work for Android Bluetooth/Wifi Sockets too.

Code snippet to go with:

```
byte[] fileBuffer = null;
int bytes = 0, expectedFileSize = 0, messageType = Constants.TYPE_IMAGE;
boolean isProcessing = false;
while (isReading) {
    try {
        if (isProcessing) {
            // Fragment arrived
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int currentSize = mmInStream.read(buffer);

            // Keep appending to the fileBuffer
            System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, fileBuffer, bytes, currentSize);
            bytes += currentSize;
            if (bytes == expectedFileSize) {
                // Your message is ready. Send it!
                sendIt(fileBuffer, messageType);
                isProcessing = false;
                bytes = 0;
            }
        } else {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
            try {
                // Message is a JSON. Next set of messages will be audio or image.
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(new String(buffer, 0, bytes));
                expectedFileSize = json.getInt(Constants.MESSAGE_SIZE);
                messageType = json.getInt(Constants.MESSAGE_TYPE);
                fileBuffer = new byte[expectedFileSize];
                isProcessing = true;
                bytes = 0;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // This is a normal message. Send it without processing.
                sendIt(buffer, Constants.TYPE_TEXT);
                isProcessing = false;
                bytes = 0;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Edits to the code to optimize it further are welcome! Hope this helps.